# Bug (?) in color of connection bars in TikZ mindmap

Tags: tikz-pgf, mindmaps

I have the following figure, with the code below:

[image: Example of minmap]

```
\documentclass{standalone} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[small mindmap]
\node[concept, concept color=green] {Green\\node}
child[concept color=blue, grow=-65] {
    node[concept] {Blue\\Node\\2}
    child[concept color=red, grow=-60] { node[concept] {Red\\Node\\3} }
    child[concept color=red, grow=-120] { node[concept] (r) {Red\\Node\\2} }
}
child[concept color=blue, grow=-120] {
    node[concept] (b) {Blue\\Node\\1}
    child[concept color=red, grow=-120] { node[concept] {Red\\Node\\1} }
};
\path (b) to[circle connection bar switch color=from (blue) to (red)] (r);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

**Main question:** Why is the color of the connection bars between the green node and the blue nodes incorrect? And how to correct this?

**Side question:** My way of placing the Red Node 2 as a child of Blue Node 2 and then connect it as I can to Blue Node 1 is kind of a ugly hack. How should one code this more properly?

**Side side question:** There is some rough description of the `mindmap` library in the Beamer user guide, but I have been unable to find some complete documentation. Does it exist?

Comment: Try without `small`.

Comment: I get the same result! (For a *minimal* example, I should have removed `small` indeed.)

Comment: Answer to side side question: mindmaps are explained in sections "6 Tutorial: A Lecture Map for Johannes" and "58 Mindmap Drawing Library" from [`pgfmanual`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf), which you can open on your system with command `texdoc --view pgfmanual`.

Comment: I'm stupid: I saw section 6, but I didn't see section 58... Well, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting `concept color=green` as a node option does not effect the connection to the first level children. Use it as an option of the `tikzpicture`.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[mindmap,concept color=green]
```

You could place the Red Node 2 as an `extra concept` of level 2 in the middle of the Red Node 1 and Red Node 3. If you name the node the children will automatically be named.

```
\documentclass{standalone} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[mindmap,concept color=green]
\node[concept](mm) {Green\\node}
child[concept color=blue, grow=-60] {
    node[concept] {Blue\\Node\\2}
    child[concept color=red, grow=-60] { node[concept] {Red\\Node\\3} }
    %child[concept color=red, grow=-120] { node[concept] (r) {Red\\Node\\2} }
}
child[concept color=blue, grow=-120] {
    node[concept] {Blue\\Node\\1}
    child[concept color=red, grow=-120] { node[concept] {Red\\Node\\1} }
};

\node[extra concept,level 2 concept,concept color=red](mm-1-1e2)at(mm|-mm-1-1){Red\\Node\\2};

\foreach \i in {1,2}
  \path (mm-\i) to[circle connection bar switch color=from (blue) to (red)] (mm-1-1e2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

There is a chapter "Mindmap Drawing Library" inside the [pgfmanual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf).

Comment: Thank you, this answers my three questions! I'll now have a look to the documentation, I'm pretty sure I can find all the answers I need (and more!).